# I broke my leg - when I actually did something to break it

Tags: meaning

> I broke my leg.

I know what it means.

But if I actually did something directly to my leg to break it, how should I say it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I broke my leg.

This covers any instance of your leg breaking, whether caused by you or not. It is the all-purpose expression that omits agency.

If you wish to ascribe agency, use a different subject:

> Tom broke my leg.

Now it's clear that Tom is the agent of  your misfortune.

If you want to say that you were the cause of your own broken bone, you have to add some specifics:

> I broke my leg with a hammer.

This may elicit the question "Did you do it on purpose?" To clear that up you can either deny that was your intention, or else confirm it:

> I broke my leg deliberately.
>   I broke my leg to get out of the Army.

Note that most actions involving you receiving a broken leg are still covered by the simple statement "I broke my leg." This covers car crashes, mishaps with tools, sports accidents, and just about any other misfortune.